# Ruby: Why is my method non-destructive?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create two methods, one of which will destructively add "i" to any string, and one of which will do the same non-destructively.

```
def add_i(string)
  new_string = string + "i"
end

def add_i!(string)
  string = string + "i"
end
```

My questions are:

1. Both of these methods are non-destructive, even though I do not replace the argument in the second method with a new variable. Why?
2. In general, how do I convert a non-destructive method into a destructive one and vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer lies in the scope of the vars and the behavior of the methods/operators. the left hand side (left to the = )**string** inside **add_i!** is a different **string** than the one passed in (the right side **string** and the method arg). The old string continues to live on but the string var points to the new one.

to make the 2nd method "destructive" you could do something like:

```
def add!(string)
  string << "i"
end
```

as a rule of the thumb, you need to understand if the methods/operators you are applying are operating on the data itself or are returning a copy of the data (for example the '+' upstairs returns a copy)

an easy way of dealing with string and making sure you don't destroy the data is to use dup() on whatever is passed in and after that operate on the copy.

Comment: "*the string inside add_i! is a different string than the one passed in*". This is badly worded to imply `add_i!` is passed a copy of `string`. `string` in `add_i!` is the same object as passed in until `string = string + "i"`.

Comment: yup. lemme see if I can reword it

Answer (score 2):

The problem is [`+` returns a copy of the string](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-2B).  I guess this is analgous to adding numbers which will return two numbers. `string += 'i'` also makes a copy. This a bit surprising, but it is the same as what numbers do.

You can see this by checking the `object_id` at each point.

```
def add_i!(string)
  puts "string passed into add_i! #{string.object_id}"
  string = string + "i"
  puts "string in add_i after + i #{string.object_id}"
end

foo = "blah"
puts "string about to be passed into add_i! #{foo.object_id}"
add_i!(foo)
puts "string after calling add_i! #{foo.object_id}"

string about to be passed into add_i! 70364940039240
string passed into add_i! 70364940039240
string in add_i after + i 70364940039020
string after calling add_i! 70364940039240
```

Note that `string in add_i after + i` has a different object id.

`<<` and [`concat`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-2B) both append to the existing string. `concat` should probably be `concat!` but it isn't.